# Data isn't refreshing properly on Angular Material Table in a Material Tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm following a video tutorial building a contact manager app on Angular Material Design that was designed for version 5 of Angular and Angular Material but I'm using Angular 7.0.4 and Material 7.2.0.

I'm implementing Material tabs with two tabs separating the bio of contacts from notes for those contacts. The first tab properly pulls the correct bio for each but the second tab, the notes tab, doesn't refresh. The second tab will maintain the notes from the last contact of when the browser refreshed no matter which contact is shown. Since it defaults to the first contact, the first contact's notes are shown for every contact.s notes.

[image]

Change of Contact & bio is controlled by the following SidNav component:

sidenav.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';

const SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT = 720;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  private mediaMatcher: MediaQueryList =
    matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`);

    users: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(
    zone: NgZone,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router) {
    this.mediaMatcher.addListener(mql =>
    zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`)));
  }

  @ViewChild(MatSidenav) sidenav: MatSidenav;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.userService.users;
    this.userService.loadAll();

    this.users.subscribe(data => {
      if (data.length > 0) this.router.navigate(['contactmanager', data[0].id]);
    });

    this.router.events.subscribe(() => {

      // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
      if (this.isScreenSmall())
        this.sidenav.close();
    })

  }

  isScreenSmall(): boolean {
    return this.mediaMatcher.matches;
  }

}
```

notes.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Note } from '../../models/note';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notes',
  templateUrl: './notes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notes.component.scss']
})
export class NotesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() notes: Note[];

  displayedColumns = ['position', 'title', 'date'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Note>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Note>(this.notes);
  }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private _users: BehaviorSubject<User[]>;

  private dataStore: {
    users: User[]
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.dataStore = { users: [] };
    this._users = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);
  }

  get users(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this._users.asObservable();
  }

  userById(id: number) {
    return this.dataStore.users.find(x => x.id == id);
  }

  loadAll() {
    const usersUrl = 'https://angular-material-api.azurewebsites.net/users';

    return this.http.get<User[]>(usersUrl)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataStore.users = data;
        this._users.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).users);
      }, error => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
        console.log("Failed to fetch users");
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Can u show the code which should trigger change of bio?

Comment: I added the Sidenav component code to the top. The Contacts\Bio are triggered there.

Comment: Can you add some more code, especially the templates so we can understand the issue better? Or maybe add a stackblitz?

Comment: The problem resolved itself when I finished the tutorial. Perhaps a cache problem but I doubt it. I have moved on from this particular problem. I think I am getting the same problem in a different tutorial now. The id parameter isn't being passed properly. I won't quit so I will probably be posting a different question soon. Thanks to all.